# Magento: When I move site in live display error: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2054] The server requested authentication method unknown to the client

Tags: magento

There has been an error processing your request

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2054] The server requested authentication method unknown to the client


Trace:
#0 /home/claddingstor/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(111): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->_connect()
#1 /home/claddingstor/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(320): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->_connect()
#2 /home/claddingstor/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(460): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->_connect()
#3 /home/claddingstor/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('SET NAMES utf8', Array)
#4 /home/claddingstor/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(428): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('SET NAMES utf8', Array)
#5 /home/claddingstor/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource.php(179): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('SET NAMES utf8')
#6 /home/claddingstor/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource.php(110): Mage_Core_Model_Resource->_newConnection('pdo_mysql', Object(Mage_Core_Model_Config_Element))
#7 /home/claddingstor/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Abstract.php(320): Mage_Core_Model_Resource->getConnection('core_write')
#8 /home/claddingstor/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Abstract.php(350): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract->_getConnection('write')
#9 /home/claddingstor/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Abstract.php(335): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract->_getWriteAdapter()
#10 /home/claddingstor/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Cache.php(53): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract->_getReadAdapter()
#11 /home/claddingstor/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Cache.php(478): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Cache->getAllOptions()
#12 /home/claddingstor/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Cache.php(520): Mage_Core_Model_Cache->_initOptions()
#13 /home/claddingstor/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1183): Mage_Core_Model_Cache->canUse('config')
#14 /home/claddingstor/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php(414): Mage_Core_Model_App->useCache('config')
#15 /home/claddingstor/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php(294): Mage_Core_Model_Config->_canUseCacheForInit()
#16 /home/claddingstor/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(413): Mage_Core_Model_Config->loadModulesCache()
#17 /home/claddingstor/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(343): Mage_Core_Model_App->_initModules()
#18 /home/claddingstor/public_html/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#19 /home/claddingstor/public_html/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#20 {main}
```

Comment: Which version of php and mysql you are using?

Answer (score 0):

Check the magento requirements (php version, libs, mysql version etc.)

http://merch.docs.magento.com/ce/user_guide/Magento_Community_Edition_User_Guide.html#magento/magento-compability-check.html

Maybe also this can be helpful:

https://secure.vexxhost.com/support/index.php?/Knowledgebase/Article/View/126/8/mysql-error-sqlstatehy000-2054-the-server-requested-authentication-method-unknown-to-the-client

Comment: Ok but all version is up to date in server, So what I do to solved that?

Comment: If its possible, upload on your host magento-check.php and provide access to this file.
Also please provide access to your phpinfo.
The most probably the problem is with server configuration. Access details are OK, otherwise your error message told something like 'incorrect host/username/...'